# Unable to format a timestamp to a date in vba

Tags: vba, date, timestamp

I'm trying to format a timestamp `1624373961042` to a date but the way I've tried below always gives me `overflow` error. I was expecting to get this date `2021-06-22` from that timestamp. How can I make it possible?

```
Sub getDate()
    Dim tDate As Long, timestamp As String
    timestamp = "1624373961042"
    
    tDate = Int(timestamp) / 1000
    MsgBox Format(tDate, "yyyymmdd")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Int` returns the Integer part of a number, you should use `Cint` or in this case `CLng` to avoid the overflow.

Comment: You need to do: `tDate = Clng(cdbl(timestamp)/84600000+2569)`  The timstamp is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.  Excel days since 12/31/1899.

Comment: sorry should be: `tDate = Clng(cdbl(timestamp)/84600000+25569)`

Comment: One note: CLng will round the date.  You can go back to INT which will truncate the decimal without rounding.

Comment: Your suggestion let the script got rid of that error @Scott Craner. However, I get wrong date now. This is `20220728` what I'm getting at this moment whereas the right date should be `20210622`. Thanks.

Comment: sorry it should be: `tDate = INT(cdbl(timestamp)/86400000+25569)`  I had the 4 and 6 reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to divide the number by the number of milliseconds in a day: `86400000`

then add the number of days from 12/31/1899 and 1/1/1970: 25569

```
Sub getDate()
    Dim tDate As Long, timestamp As String
    timestamp = "1624373961042"
    
    tDate = Int((CDbl(timestamp) / 86400000) + 25569)
    MsgBox Format(tDate, "yyyymmdd")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So, notning is impossible as long as delevopers like you are there, right? Thanks a trillion.